# How to run rsync on specific users home folders based the results from a shell script?

Tags: macos, unix, applescript, rsync

Alright, so I am trying to make a backup mac backup script which uses an embeded rsync command. That all works but I want to be able to run a backup for each home folder of users with a uid of 500 or greater. So my code below mounts the external server drive >> finds the users with a uid equal to or higher than 500 >> parses that result into segments >> [area that I need help with] >> runs rsync

I know I will need to make the do shell for the rsync command into a loop but not sure how I can get it to loop while inserting the name for each home folder for the backup.

ie, on my machine I have three user with uids over 500 and would need it to loop through the rsync command three times, once for each users homefolder

```
set turnips to "MacBackups"
tell application "Finder"
if not (disk "[my server name here]" exists) then
    mount volume "[my smb server name here]" & turnips
end if
end tell

set homeFolders to paragraphs of (do shell script "dscl /Local/Default -list /Users uid | awk '$2 >= 500 && $0 !~ /^_/ { print $1 }'")
set firstFileObject to POSIX file (item 1 of homeFolders)




do shell script "rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete --ignore-existing -u -c -z '/Users/[THIS IS WHERE I WANT IT TO CYCLE THROUGH EACH HOME FOLDER FOR BACKUP ONTO THE SERVER]' '/Volumes/MacBackups'" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Assuming the value of `homeFolders` is an Array that you want to loop over. Try placing your `do shell script ...` in a [repeat with](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128481) statement. For example: `repeat with aThing in homeFolders`, then reference `aThing` via your `do shell script` during each turn of the loop.